# Stop Windows 10 resizing icons & windows when screen size is changed

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I use my 40" TV as my computer monitor. It is 5 feet from my head. I set the computer screen to 1600x900 when used as a monitor and 1920x1080 when watching HD videos. Windows 10. Until a week or so ago, when I switched to 1920x1080 my icons and windows appeared smaller as their size in pixels did not change. Now when I switch to 1920x1080 the icons and windows are enlarged so the screen looks about the same. This means now I am never sure what my screen size is. Does anyone know if this resizing of icons and windows can be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Display Settings (Right-click desktop), then head to Scale and layout section. Look at Change the size of text, apps and other items.

Now this is where you set the scaling setting. Go to Advanced scaling settings, Custom Scaling and pick one from 100-200%, such as 125 or 150, or 200. Now it is hard locked, the size of the icons in terms of pixels should stay the same.

Comment: Further info: I'm 81 years old, started working with computers in 1968 (maintaining Univac mainframes), my first PC was 2nd gen, a clock speed of 8MHz instead of 4.77. My memory is starting to let me down too.
I just hope the next time MS deides to "improve" Windows 10 it's no worse than this one.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice works just as you said. Unfortunately I have 110 icons on screen in 10 rows, and if I enlarge them to 125% they take 8 rows and become randomly organized. I'll stick with what I'm comfortable with.